# Non-Data Descriptor That Takes an Optional Arguement

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-descriptors

I want to have a class which has several properties which represent time-series of data. E.g.

```
import datetime

def get_assigned_to(title, date=None):
    if date is None:
        date = dt.date.today()
    ...


class Todo(object):

    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        self._assigned_to = get_assigned_to

    @special_property
    def assigned_to(self, date=None):
        return self._assigned_to(self._title, date)
```

Ideally I'd then be able to do something like

```
>>> world_domination = Todo("Take over world")
>>> world_domination.assigned_to
'Alice'
>>> world_domination.assigned_to(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1))
'Bob'
```

Or even

```
>>> world_domination.assigned_to[date]
```

or

```
>>> world_domination.assigned_to.on(date)
```

Is there a way to write a descriptor that takes an optional argument like that? It doesn't need to be able set the property. Just get it.

Comment: Using ```assigned_to``` for the dual purposes of defining the time at which a task is assigned as well as the individual to which the task is assigned seems to me to be syntactically confusing and violates the idea that a function/method should serve a single purpose.  Why not use ```assigned_on``` to set/retrieve the time at which a task is assigned and ```assigned_to``` to set/retrieve the individual assigned to the task.   You should then be able to use @property to implement the getter and setter functions for each.

Comment: That's essentially what I'm doing at the moment. Using the property decorator as function to do  `assigned _to = property(get_assigned_to)`.

Comment: So if you are doing that, what is you specific problem?